# How do I prove that the given function is continuous and monotonically increasing?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

How do I prove that the following function is continuous and monotonically increasing?

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{e^x-1}{x}  & \text{if $x \neq0$ } \\ 1 & \text{if $x=0$ } \end{cases}$$

I tried to show that it's continuous by that it's always continuous, even when $x=0$ (because by definition it becomes $1$ and $1$ is in the upper functions definition) but it's not sufficient and I don't know how to write it mathematically, and without that I can not step forward to prove it being monotonously rising.

Then to show it's monotonously rising, we can see that the derivative is $\frac{e^xx-e^x+1}{x^2}$ (it exists because the function is continuous (which I don't know how to prove yet)), and then to show that it is monotonically increasing i show that $f'(x)>0$.

Please show me the right way to do so mathematically.

Comment: How can this question possibly deserve a down vote?!

Comment: i don't know what i did wrong here. i've elaborated and asked the question as clearly as i can and specified what i tried to do, and how i want to prove.

Comment: This is a well asked question. Some people on stack just like to be mean and pretentious. Don't let it bother you.

Comment: @Joel I believe the downvote could've been a mistake.  :D It appears gone now

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I am glad to see that :)

Comment: Possibly the downvote was because the explanations offered for why the function is continuous and differentiable are nonsensical. But eventually the downvoter realized that this is exactly why the poster is asking the question, and it doesn't make sense to downvote someone for not knowing the answer to the question they are asking.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming $x\neq 0$ we have
$$ \frac{e^x-1}{x} = \frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x} e^y\,dy \stackrel{y\mapsto xz}{=} \int_{0}^{1}e^{xz}\,dz$$
hence $f(x)$ is increasing  because $x\geq y$ ensures $e^{xz}\geq e^{yz}$ for $z\in[0,1]$.
Continuity follows from the monotone/dominated convergence theorem.

Addendum: it is also straightforward to check that $f$ is convex, by just invoking [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).

Comment: Gah!  Why are you so good at these things!?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: I followed a simple principle: if something does not look too manageable, it is worth to check if it has a more manageable integral representation.

Comment: :-P Not everyone is able to see integrals the way you do

Comment: Am I missing something or is it $\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{1}e^{xz}\,dz$?

Comment: @Shuri2060: the substitution $y=xz$ cancels the $\frac{1}{x}$ factor and turns the integration range from $[0,x]$ into $[0,1]$.

Comment: Got it - tnx. Messed up the integration in my head

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how much you're allowed to assume, you might be able to answer the part about continuity by using these results:

> If $a\in\mathbb R^+$ and $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous on $F$ and $G$ respectively, then:
>
> - $f(x)+g(x)$ is continuous on $F\cap G$
> - $a^{f(x)}$ is continuous on $F$
> - If $(\forall x\in F\cap G)\,\,\,g(x)\neq0$, then $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is continuous on $F\cap G$

Using these results, you can conclude $f(x)$ is continuous on the intervals $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$.

Now, using L'Hôpital,

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}{e^x}=1$$

$\implies$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}f(x)=1=f(x)$$

Therefore $f(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$.

---

For the next part,

$$f'(x)=\frac{(x-1)e^x+1}{x^2}$$

Let $g(x)=(x-1)e^x+1$. Then

$$g'(x)=xe^x$$

$$\implies (x=0\iff g'(x)=0)$$

$$g''(x)=(x+1)e^x$$

$$\implies g''(0)=1>0$$

Now $g(0)=0 \land (x=0\iff g'(x)=0) \land g''(0)>0 \implies 0$ is the only minimum.

$$\implies(\forall x\in\mathbb R)\,\,g(x)\ge0$$

$$\implies(\forall x\in\mathbb R)\,\,f'(x)\ge0$$

$\implies(\forall x\in\mathbb R)\,\,f(x)$ is monotonically increasing.

Comment: Missing the monotone part :-)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Almost there. Digging around for the simplest way to show it

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt No, I was digging around a dead end. So yes I'm stuck. Good thing Jack D'Aurizio got it

Comment: xD okay $\color{white}{\text{Sometime's that guy is seriously too good...}}$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Now I'm unstuck haha

Comment: Your increasing proof is almost there. But you have not shown $f$ is differentiable at $0$ (only continuous), and thus cannot claim that $f'(0) \ge 0$ and therefore deduce monotonicity there. You can fix it either by proving differentiability at $0$, or by leveraging continuity and the proven increasing behavior away from $0$ to show that it holds for $0$ as well.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Isn't there a result that says: a continuous function which is monotonic and differentiable in $\mathbb R \setminus S$ where $|S|\in \mathbb R$ is monotonic in $\mathbb R$? (I know I missed that in my proof - and I should add i in, of course)

Comment: That result is what I mean by "leveraging continuity". For this function, if $a < x < 0$, then we know that $f(a) \le f(x)$. Taking the limit as $x \to 0-$, we see that $f(a) \le f(0)$. Similarly, if $b > 0$ then $f(0) \le f(b)$. Whence monotonicity holds everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If $0\leq x\leq y$ then $\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}\leq \frac{y^{n-1}}{n!}$ for all $n>0$.

Therefore $\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\sum_{n>0}\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}\leq\sum_{n>0}\frac{y^{n-1}}{n!}=\frac{e^y-1}{y}$.

Comment: What about negative $x$ and / or $y$? You've only checked a quarter of the cases.

Comment: Also you probably should have at least a minimal argument for why the inequality of the terms implies the same inequality for the sums. At a minimum you need convergence so both sides make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Not a proof, but an animation loop that should make the claim "obvious". The function $f(x)$ is the slope of the secant line between $(0, 1)$ and $(x, e^{x})$ if $x \neq 0$, or the slope of the tangent line if $x = 0$. Since the exponential function is smooth (continuously differentiable) and convex, this slope increases continuously with $x$:

[image: Secant slopes of exp increase continuously]